# MySql count with GROUP BY returns 1 even when count is 0

Tags: mysql, count

I have two tables in MySql i.e., subjects and photos and I wished to count the number of photos on each subjects

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, count(a.id) as `refcount`, 
FROM `subjects` a 
LEFT JOIN `photos` b ON (a.id = b.subject_id)
GROUP by a.id
ORDER BY a.name";
```

returns 1 even when the rowcount()=0.  How to fix it

I tried various MySql syntax including count(field), but in vain

Comment: Bad habbits to kick: [using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: COUNT() by a column which is a part of grouping expression can return zero only for a row where this column value is NULL. If COUNT() is zero but the column value is not NULL then this row not exists, hence it is not present in the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to `count` photos.id (b.id), if no photos are found for the given subject, the query will return null, count(null) = 0.

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, count(b.id) as `refcount`
FROM `subjects` a 
LEFT JOIN `photos` b ON a.id = b.subject_id
GROUP by a.id, a.name
ORDER BY a.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this: `SELECT a.id, a.name, SUM(IF(b.id IS NULL, 0, 1)) as refcount, FROM subjects a LEFT JOIN photos b ON (a.id = b.subject_id) GROUP by a.id order by a.name`.

PS: I didn't try it